# use \item in overpic package

Tags: itemize, overpic

I tried to write several items on a photo.
I used Overpic package for it but the latex returns an error.
part of my tex:

```
   

    \begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth,grid=true]
        {img/backgoals.png}
        \put(100,40){
    \begin{itemize}
        \item hello word
    \end{itemize}}
\end{overpic}
```

error:

```
Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item. ^^I^^I\end{itemize}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! Have you checked the correct use of brackets in your code? For example `\begin{itemize` should be `\begin{itemize}`. Also, please add a Minimum Working Example (MWE) so we can reproduce your error.

Comment: @manooooh I edited post and updates error

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.